# is site.xml compulsory for eclipse update site?

Tags: eclipse, p2

I have used eclipse [Features And Bundles Publisher](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_publisher.html) to create a p2 metadata folder. But failed add the same folder as local site as  eclipse keep on complaining  [Unable to find the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ8ww.png).
I could find content.xml and artifacts.xml but site.xml NOT generated through publisher command. I doubt if I have to create a site.xml manually.
FYI I am using eclipse KeplerSR2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you must have site.xml for update site from [update_site](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fupdate_site.htm)

> To create an update site you must develop a site.xml file and build the site. PDE provides an editor and project for creating sites. A site will contain one or more features organized into categories.

See how to create [site.xml](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fupdate_site.htm)

Comment: A site.xml is one way to generate an update site. However since Eclipse 3.5, the update site does not need to contain the site.xml file.

Comment: @oberlies I dont know about 3.5, but yes as per Luna 4.4 doc it says you must need site.xml. Please see the link in ans.

Comment: The documentation talk about "building a site". The question was about the result, i.e. an update site. And the update site doesn't need a site.xml.

Comment: @oberlies In that doc last paragraph says "These files, along with "site.xml", collectively form an Eclipse update site."  These files-> content.xml and artifacts.xml

Comment: Interesting. But then the documentation is at least imprecise (if not wrong). Technically, p2 will not look at the `site.xml` if a `content.xml` or `content.jar` is present.

Comment: But at the end the basic question what he meant was (if not wrong), he do not wanted to  create a site.xml manually.

Answer (score 3):

The p2 publisher should create a structure like this. Depending on pack attributed the content and artifact repository files [content and artifact] might be jared.

```
<repo-root-dir>
   features
      featureA.jar
      ...
   plugins
      pluginA.jar
      ...
   content[.xml|.jar]
   artifacts[.xml|.jar]
```

You won't get and won't require an update site file.
Make sure to clean the location you use from the Eclipse -> Preferences -> Available Softwares Sites. Eclipse is caching the repo metadata.

Comment: I didn't found a way to cleanup the eclipse update site metadata cache. Deleted the entry from Eclipse->Preferences -> Available Softwares Sites but If I add the metadata folder as local software sites error comes as "There are no categorized items" so can't add the metadata folder as software site.

Comment: You can uncheck the "Group by Category" checkbox inside the "Add Software Site" dialog. Then you should see your features. If you don't have features and no groups, you won't see anything inside the dialog.
Create either a container feature or a p2 category for grouping and easing the handling of your plugins with p2. (feature is simpler, cause this can be just included into your existing publisher workflow).